# Redirect Causing WSOD

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

I'm working on Magento 1.7 (I know - in process of upgrading to 2) and made a custom form as a Magento plugin. Everything upto the redirect works - but I'm not sure why or how to debug.

This is my `sendEmail()` function:

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');

$mail->setBody($this->emailHtml($code));
$mail->setFromName('MPW Site');
$mail->setToEmail($to);
$mail->setSubject('Thank You For Registering Your Atom Battery');
$mail->setType('html');

try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
    $this->_redirect('custom-page-?code='. $code);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send');
}
```

However, this snippet results in a White Screen of Death - so I put this in my index.php file to try and debug:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

but still - nothing on screen. `var/log` also hasn't got any files with a last edit timestamp of today on so I'm really not sure how/why the code is going askew. From what I read online, that redirect *should* work.

How do I redirect to a CMS page after my form submits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

`$this->_redirect()` is a method only available to classes extending `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` - the code I had lived inside a Block class. Hence no access to `$this->_redirect()`.

Still weird how the debug function and logging didn't pick up on it.